# html to @RestController redirecting problem -On External linux Server -But working fine on local SpringToolSuite

Tags: html, redirect, controller

Please help me in solving :
My application running good in spring tool suite , but when i deploy onto external Linux server- initially is was fine,

```
But after adding  below line  in my html page(in template folder) 
1.<td > <a th:href="@{/generateAndGetInvoicePDF(invoiceNo=${invoiceList.invoiceNo})}" style="text-decoration: none;" th:text="${invoiceList.invoiceNo}"></a>

--
It is working fine in my local machine (Spring tool Suite-localhost:8080)
--
But in my Linux server i am getting below error 
**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jun 14 08:23:32 UTC 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).**


my controller method
@GetMapping("/generateAndGetInvoicePDF")
    public ModelAndView getInvoicePdf(@RequestParam("invoiceNo") String invoiceNo) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        System.out.println(invoiceNo);
        
        List<Invoice> findByInvNo = IINservice.findAllByInvNo(invoiceNo);
        
         
        
        mav.setViewName("invoicePDF");

        return mav;
    }



this is my address bar 
**http://localhost:8080/generateAndGetInvoicePDF?invoiceNo=INV2022/01**
```

i am using
spring tool suite 4
spring boot
spring security
spring data Jpa

```
Regards,
Arun
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was because of Case sensitivity. I was using ~
{templates/invoicePDF} instead of ~{templates/InvoicePDF} (The name of the file was InvoicePDF.html)   --'I' is in upperCase

My development environment was windows but the server hosting the application was Linux so I was not seeing this issue during development since windows' paths are not case sensitive.